# Daubechies wavelet and scaling filters: Is there a better way?

Tags: c++, mathematics, c++17

I have computed the Daubechies wavelet and scaling filters in `float`, `double`, `long double`, and `quad` precision, and now want to expose these filters in a usable API. My problem is as follows: I want to make sure that these filters are correct to every single bit, so I wrote them as hexadecimal floating point literals. Then I wanted to get them to parse in the correct format, so I need to append literals like `f`, `L`, or `Q`. But to get them to parse as the correct type, I need to duplicate them over and over, resulting in a monstrous `#include` file, given [here](https://github.com/boostorg/math/blob/d7e4bf780b496cbd6140d06cccba3f0374ae9d78/include/boost/math/filters/daubechies.hpp)

The file is too big to place in the question, but here's a short sample:

```cpp
#ifndef BOOST_MATH_FILTERS_DAUBECHIES_HPP
#define BOOST_MATH_FILTERS_DAUBECHIES_HPP
#include <array>
#ifdef BOOST_HAS_FLOAT128
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
#endif
namespace boost::math::filters {

template <typename Real, unsigned p>
constexpr std::array<Real, 2*p> daubechies_scaling_filter()
{
    static_assert(sizeof(Real) <= 16, "Filter coefficients only computed up to 128 bits of precision.");
    static_assert(p < 25, "Filter coefficients only implemented up to 24.");
    if constexpr (p == 1) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Real, float>) {
            return {0x1.6a09e6p-1f, 0x1.6a09e6p-1f};
        }
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Real, double>) {
            return {0x1.6a09e667f3bcdp-1, 0x1.6a09e667f3bcdp-1};
        }
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Real, long double>) {
            return {0xb.504f333f9de6484p-4L, 0xb.504f333f9de6484p-4L};
        }
        #ifdef BOOST_HAS_FLOAT128
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Real, boost::multiprecision::float128>) {
            return {0x1.6a09e667f3bcc908b2fb1366ea95p-1Q, 0x1.6a09e667f3bcc908b2fb1366ea95p-1Q};
        }
        #endif
    }
    if constexpr (p == 2) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Real, float>) {
            return {0x1.ee8dd4p-2f, 0x1.ac4bdep-1f, 0x1.cb0bfp-3f, -0x1.0907dcp-3f};
        }
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Real, double>) {
            return {0x1.ee8dd4748bf15p-2, 0x1.ac4bdd6e3fd71p-1, 0x1.cb0bf0b6b7109p-3, -0x1.0907dc193069p-3};
        }
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Real, long double>) {
            return {0xf.746ea3a45f8a62ap-5L, 0xd.625eeb71feb8557p-4L, 0xe.585f85b5b8845bdp-6L, -0x8.483ee0c9834834cp-6L};
        }
        #ifdef BOOST_HAS_FLOAT128
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Real, boost::multiprecision::float128>) {
            return {0x1.ee8dd4748bf14c548b969de58fap-2Q, 0x1.ac4bdd6e3fd70aae9f48d8a63d1bp-1Q, 0x1.cb0bf0b6b7108b79b4bf11d08b16p-3Q, -0x1.0907dc1930690697b13714fd4a15p-3Q};
        }
        #endif
    }
...

template<class Real, size_t p>
std::array<Real, 2*p> daubechies_wavelet_filter() {
    std::array<Real, 2*p> g;
    auto h = daubechies_scaling_filter<Real, p>();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < g.size(); i += 2)
    {
        g[i] = h[g.size() - i - 1];
        g[i+1] = -h[g.size() - i - 2];
    }
    return g;
}
```

Is there a way to only state the filter coefficients once, with the maximum allowed precision, and have the compiler parse it as the user's desired type, and preserve the `constexpr`?

Is keep the filter coefficients `constexpr` a sensible desideratum here? (I'm not even sure that I should make `p` a template parameter. . .) If so, note that the scaling filters are `constexpr`, but the wavelet filters are not. Is there a way around that?

C++17 solutions are acceptable; C++20 solutions are  . . . less so, but if they can be shown to dramatically improve the code that's what language updates are for correct?

Comment: @Emma: I already know they are correct.